# Does "Environment.Is64BitProcess" equal to "IntPtr.Size == 8"?

Tags: .net, environment, intptr

Since "IntPtr.Size" checks the size of int's pointer based on the current process, is it the same as "Environment.Is64BitProcess"?

If yes, why can I only see "return true/false" (if you use dnSpy to refactor the code from "System")?

[image: dnSpy]

If not, any differences between them? Where to use what?

Comment: Personal opinion: always use `Environment.Is64BitProcess`, because it's crystal clear what you're trying to check. Wth the `IntPtr.Size` it needs a bit more thinking to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern runtimes (net core) `Is64BitProcess` is defined through `IntPtr.Size == 8`. See [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a8baca13ea08916e32b57413488a6cd0a20c6d13/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Environment.cs#L166)

You see `false` because you're inspecting 32-bit mscorlib. 64-bit is located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` and always returns `true`